# Print Image to Printer Thermal but the result give weird character Android

Tags: java, android, printing

I build print service for Google Chrome browser. technically I convert the PDF into image then convert it to byte array then do print. But on some device give the weird character on result. Here is the code :

PrintService.class

```
byte[] image = bitmapToBytes(rescaledBitmap, false);
byte[][] bytesToPrint = convertGSv0ToEscAsterisk(image);
timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());

for (byte[] bytes : bytesToPrint) {
    this.mOutputStream.write(bytes);
    this.mOutputStream.flush();
}
String endLine = "\n\n\n\n\n";
this.mOutputStream.write(endLine.getBytes());
....
....

public static byte[] bitmapToBytes(Bitmap bitmap, boolean gradient) {
    int bitmapWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
    int bitmapHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
    int bytesByLine = (bitmapWidth + 7) / 8;
    byte[] imageBytes = new byte[bytesByLine * bitmapHeight + 8];
    int i = 8;
    int greyscaleCoefficientInit = 0;
    int gradientStep = 6;
    double colorLevelStep = 765.0 / (15 * gradientStep + gradientStep - 1);

    for (int posY = 0; posY < bitmapHeight; posY++) {
        int greyscaleCoefficient = greyscaleCoefficientInit;
        int greyscaleLine = posY % gradientStep;

        for (int j = 0; j < bitmapWidth; j += 8) {
            int b = 0;

            for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
                int posX = j + k;

                if (posX < bitmapWidth) {
                    int color = bitmap.getPixel(posX, posY);
                    int red = Color.red(color);
                    int green = Color.green(color);
                    int blue = Color.blue(color);

                    if ((gradient && (red + green + blue) < ((greyscaleCoefficient * gradientStep + greyscaleLine) * colorLevelStep))
                            || (!gradient && (red < 160 || green < 160 || blue < 160))) {
                        b |= 1 << (7 - k);
                    }

                    greyscaleCoefficient += 5;
                    if (greyscaleCoefficient > 15) {
                        greyscaleCoefficient -= 16;
                    }
                }
            }
            imageBytes[i++] = (byte) b;
        }

        greyscaleCoefficientInit += 2;
        if (greyscaleCoefficientInit > 15) {
            greyscaleCoefficientInit = 0;
        }
    }

    imageBytes[4] = (byte) (bytesByLine & 0xFF);
    imageBytes[5] = (byte) ((bytesByLine >> 8) & 0xFF);
    imageBytes[6] = (byte) (bitmapHeight & 0xFF);
    imageBytes[7] = (byte) ((bitmapHeight >> 8) & 0xFF);

    return imageBytes;
}

public static byte[][] convertGSv0ToEscAsterisk(byte[] bytes) {
    final byte LF = 0x0A;
    final byte[] LINE_SPACING_30 = {0x1b, 0x33, 0x1e};
    final byte[] LINE_SPACING_24 = {0x1b, 0x33, 0x18};

    int
            xL = bytes[4] & 0xFF,
            xH = bytes[5] & 0xFF,
            yL = bytes[6] & 0xFF,
            yH = bytes[7] & 0xFF,
            bytesByLine = xH * 256 + xL,
            dotsByLine = bytesByLine * 8,
            nH = dotsByLine / 256,
            nL = dotsByLine % 256,
            imageHeight = yH * 256 + yL,
            imageLineHeightCount = (int) Math.ceil((double) imageHeight / 24.0),
            imageBytesSize = 6 + bytesByLine * 24;

    byte[][] returnedBytes = new byte[imageLineHeightCount + 2][];
    returnedBytes[0] = LINE_SPACING_24;
    for (int i = 0; i < imageLineHeightCount; ++i) {
        int pxBaseRow = i * 24;
        byte[] imageBytes = new byte[imageBytesSize];
        imageBytes[0] = 0x1B;
        imageBytes[1] = 0x2A;
        imageBytes[2] = 0x21;
        imageBytes[3] = (byte) nL;
        imageBytes[4] = (byte) nH;
        for (int j = 5; j < imageBytes.length; ++j) {
            int
                    imgByte = j - 5,
                    byteRow = imgByte % 3,
                    pxColumn = imgByte / 3,
                    bitColumn = 1 << (7 - pxColumn % 8),
                    pxRow = pxBaseRow + byteRow * 8;
            for (int k = 0; k < 8; ++k) {
                int indexBytes = bytesByLine * (pxRow + k) + pxColumn / 8 + 8;

                if (indexBytes >= bytes.length) {
                    break;
                }

                boolean isBlack = (bytes[indexBytes] & bitColumn) == bitColumn;
                if (isBlack) {
                    imageBytes[j] |= 1 << 7 - k;
                }
            }
        }
        imageBytes[imageBytes.length - 1] = LF;
        returnedBytes[i + 1] = imageBytes;
    }
    returnedBytes[returnedBytes.length - 1] = LINE_SPACING_30;
    return returnedBytes;
}
```

On some device, result is like below below :

[image: weird_characted]

But on some device the result is normal too. I stuck fixing this for couple days. Is there another method to convert bitmap to byte array for printing to thermal printer? I really appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occur because print processing still running but the socket was close. So the weird character is part of previous process. But this problem only occur in some printer devices (with same length bytes). So I add some UI (time in second) for user to define time to close socket after printing (by default still is 0).

```
for (byte[] bytes : bytesToPrint) {
    this.mOutputStream.write(bytes);
    this.mOutputStream.flush();
}
String endLine = "\n\n\n\n\n";
this.mOutputStream.write(endLine.getBytes());

Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(() -> {
        try {
            closeBTPrinter();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }, socketTimeOut);
```